# SqlCommand state closed when SqlConnection state is open

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqldatareader

I am having an intermittent issue with a `SqlDataRreader` class where I have opened a `SqlConnection` and its state is `OPEN`, but when I create a `SqlCommand` with that `SqlConnection`, the `SqlConnection`'s state is `CLOSED`. This only occurs approximately 1 in 10 attempts, and so it might be a timing issue.

Note that rather than putting the connection in a Using block, I open/close the connection independently as I usually execute multiple commands at once, however the issue usually occurs on the first time a command is executed on a connection that has just been opened.

The connection code is:

```
    private SqlConnection sql;

    public Result Connect(string database)
    {
        string connection = Config.environments[Config.environment][database];
        try
        {
            // Create and open the connection
            sql = new SqlConnection(connection);
            sql.Open();

            if (sql == null || sql.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                return new Result(false, "Connect to Database", "Could not connect to database [" + connection + "]");
            return new Result(true, "Connect to Database", "Connected to database [" + connection + "]");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return new Result(false, "Connect to Database", "Could not connect to database [" + connection + "] " + e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

The run command code is:

```
    private DataTable RunSql(string statement)
    {
        if (sql == null || sql.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            throw new ScriptException("Cannot execute SQL command, no database connection established [" + statement + "]");

        // Create and execute the SQL statement
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(statement, sql))
        {
            command.CommandTimeout = Config.sqlTimeout;

            try
            {
                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader()) // ERROR OCCURS HERE! - sql.State is OPEN, but command.State is CLOSED ???
                {
                    // Check is the reader has any rresults
                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        DataTable data = new DataTable();
                        data.Load(reader);
                        return data;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new Exception("No results found for statement: " + statement + ", on server: " + sql.DataSource + ", in database: " + sql.Database);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException)
            {
                //Log things here
            }

            throw new ScriptException("Error executing sql command: " + statement);
        }
    }
```

The code that reproduces the issue (occasionally):

```
    private DataTable RunSingleCommand(string database, string command)
    {
        Log(Connect(database));
        return RunSql(command);
    }
```

Comment: Well you never make sure the connection has successfully been opened before running the command...

Comment: @Grant, is there reasoning behind that? The SqlConnection is OPEN at the point that the exception occurs, so the connection has not timed out.

Comment: @Ignaus, is the check `if (sql == null || sql.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)` not enough to verify the connection is open? This occurs twice before the command is created.

Comment: Yes but in the case that it does not open successfully, you call the `RunSql` method anyway... I just think it's worse practice then for example only calling `RunSql` if the connection opened successfully.

Comment: The connection state is checked on the first line of RunSql, and if the connection isn't open it aborts... Yes there are prettier ways I could ensure the connection is open, but that is not the issue as the connection IS open according to `sql`. My question is why would `command` have a different connection state to `sql`.

Comment: You're right, as long as your code gracefully handles the exception, you should be fine. As for the problem at hand, I generally prefer instantiating my command objects _before_ opening the connection, and I never once remember getting an error like this. Try calling `Connect` _after_ the `SqlCommand` has been instantiated? (I have no idea what this would fix but it's just a suggestion)

Comment: Also I can't help but notice that your `SqlConnection` is never _closed_. This is something you should look into if you aren't already doing it in some other code.

Comment: Where are you closing the connection?

Comment: What is your reason for not wrapping the connection in a `using` statement?

Comment: SqlConnection It is closed later on in code that I didn't include as it is never reached due to this error. The exception that is happening is occurring seconds after the connection is opened, and the first time it is used.

Comment: It is not wrapped in a using statement because I found the database sometimes hangs and takes 5-10 seconds to open the connection, as I often do 5 or so commands in a row, I wanted to be able to call RunSql 5 times without having to re-create the connection each time.

Comment: try to add finally clause to close your connection, it may because of this

Comment: @Scotty If you used using statments .NET would re-use connections put back in to the connection pool.

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain, I did not know that, thanks for the tip. I am happy to convert to the common practice of creating my connection in a Using block if the connection will be preserved for later use. Hopefully this resolves the problem, although I don't see what would cause the SqlCommand connection to get out of sync with the SqlConnection in the first place.

Comment: I would bet a fair bit that your issue is that multiple threads are calling these methods - so what happens is that one thread has assigned a new `Connection` to your `sql` variable. Then it `Open`s it. Then it goes to *use it* and before it manages to, the second thread assigns a new `Connection` to your `sql` variable. Now, before this second thread manages to `Open` it, you first thread now reads `sql`, gets the closed connection, and then you get the symptoms you're describing.

Comment: I think you might be right Damien, I introduced a race condition which is more noticeable when the database server is under load and starts behaving sluggishly

Comment: @Scotty Here is the MSDN documenation on connection pooling for more info about how it works: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

What I can suggest is inside the Connection command before opening the connection , give a condition check to know whether the connection is currently open or not. Only if its in closed mode open the new connection

```
try
{
    // Create and open the connection
    sql = new SqlConnection(connection);

    if (sql.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
    {  
        sql.Open();
    }

    return new Result(true, "Connect to Database", "Connected to database [" + connection + "]"); 
}    
catch (Exception e) 
{
    return new Result(false, "Connect to Database", "Could not connect to database [" + connection + "] " + e.ToString());
}
```